# Install Err no package conf file message_generation

Tags: ros, cmake, groovy-beta, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install groovy on OSx 10.8.2, following this guide

hxxp://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

when i configure the build this happens

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'std_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(std_msgs)
CMake Error at build/devel/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"message_generation" with any of the following names:

```
message_generationConfig.cmake
message_generation-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "message_generation" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "message_generation_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "message_generation" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
std_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Can someone please help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50802/install-err-no-package-conf-file-message_generation/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem while installing groovy on Arch Linux.

I fixed it by cloning into the repository (and message_runtime) in groovy_underlay thusly:

```
cd ~/groovy_underlay
git clone https://github.com/ros/message_generation.git
git clone https://github.com/ros/message_runtime.git
```

---

Originally posted by [yoos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1207/yoos/) with karma: 78 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4